# Inserting image and data along with date using ajax to database

Tags: php, ajax, database, upload

I want to submit form data to the database using Ajax, It has image date and some more values which are not inserted into a database

I am trying this in localhost with PHP and mySQL

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#butsave').on('click', function() {
        $("#butsave").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var candidate_key=$("#candidate_key").val();
      var candidate_employer=$("#candidate_employer").val();
     var candidate_ex=$("#candidate_ex").val();
var optionyes=$("#optionyes").val();
var e_date=$("#e_date").val();
var s_date=$("#s_date").val();
var candidate_ctc_ex=$("#candidate_ctc_ex").val();
var candidate_ctc=$("#candidate_ctc").val();
var candidate_email=$("#candidate_email").val();
var candidate_address=$("#candidate_address").val();
var candidate_mobile=$("#candidate_mobile").val();
var candidate_name=$("#candidate_name").val();
var mms_pic=$("#mms_pic").val();
        if( candidate_mobile!="" && candidate_email!="" && candidate_name!=""){
$.ajax({
url: "index1.php",
type: "POST",
mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
data: {
candidate_key:candidate_key,
candidate_employer:candidate_employer,
candidate_ex:candidate_ex,
optionyes:optionyes,
e_date:e_date,(This is the date which is in the proper format i am taking from date picker yy-mm-dd)
s_date:s_date,
candidate_ctc_ex:candidate_ctc_ex,
candidate_ctc:candidate_ctc,
candidate_email:candidate_email,
candidate_address:candidate_address,
candidate_mobile:candidate_mobile,
candidate_name:candidate_name,
mms_pic:mms_pic (This is the picture or document file)  },
cache: false,
success: function(dataResult){
var dataResult = JSON.parse(dataResult);
console.log(dataResult);
if(dataResult.statusCode==200){
                        $("#butsave").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $('#fupForm').find('input:text').val('');
                        $("#success").show();
                        $('#success').html('Data added successfully !');                        
                    }
                    else if(dataResult.statusCode==201){
                       alert("Error occured !");
                    }
                    });}
        else{
            alert('Please fill all the field !');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position

Comment: You tagged the question with PHP, but posted JavaScript. Which is it? Both? You get a syntax error in Javascript, but the problem is most likely in PHP, so you would need to show your PHP code as well. Also check the response from the server in navigation tab in your browser. There is probably an error thrown by PHP.

Comment: The JavaScript part does not seem to receive correctly formatted JSON data. Your PHP script is in charge of generating that JSON data. It appears to not be doing that properly. That is not what I would call “extremely okay”, I would call that faulty. Start doing some proper debugging, by checking how that request actually got answered by the server in your browser dev tools, network panel.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check you’re not attempting to JSON.parse() an already parsed JSON object.

Remove this line from your success callback to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for your revert, I have removed it but nothing is working, Now console stop giving me an error but values are not going in console.